# WPF - datagrid - display a text box to set the value by user when its row was selected

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a data grid that includes a list of stock items that are displayed as rows. How can I implement in which a text box is displayed for entering the desired order quantity when the user selects the item row? thanks in advance.

XAML

```
<DataGrid.Columns>              
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=ItemId}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="InStock" Binding="{Binding Path=InStock}"></DataGridTextColumn>             
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" x:Name="QuantityTextBox" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use `DataGridTemplateColumn as the following :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Quantity}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Quantity,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" PreviewTextInput="CheckIsInteger" TextChanged="QuantityChanged" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Then you may also check that user only inserts numbers (CheckIsInteger) :

```
private void CheckIsInteger(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    int parsedValue;
    if (!int.TryParse(e.Text, out parsedValue))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```